# How to set full div clickable?

Tags: javascript, css, html, clickable

I have this code for div

```
      <div align="center" id="1_2" class="class_div" onclick="DoAction(1)" style="float: left;  height: 60px; width: 250px; margin: 10px"><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Class :Class-1</h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Class Teacher :Manan</div>
```

When cursor moves on the div it shows text-cursor . I want that div to be clickable and the click-cursor should come there.How could this be done.Please help??

Comment: Side note: Although that `id` value is valid in HTML5, it's invalid in HTML4 and earlier and in CSS. Since CSS's rules for `id` values are the most strict, I'd recommend sticking with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it fully clickable, you need to add `cursor:pointer;`  `display:inline-table;` `text-align:center;` properties respectively to the div.

Without `display:inline-table`, the whole of the div will not be clickable and will create a gap between two lines of text.

Here is the [WORKING SOLUTION](http://jsfiddle.net/g6J3E/)

**The HTML:**

```
<div align="center" id="1_2" class="class_div" onclick="DoAction(1)" style="float: left;  height: 60px; width: 250px; margin: 10px"><h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Class :Class-1</h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Class Teacher :Manan</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
div{cursor:pointer; display:inline-table; text-align:center;}
```

Hope the helps.

*PS: I have illustrated with div as the selector, but alternatively, you can apply the styles to the class also.*

Comment: I believe by just applying cursor:pointer to div is enough? What is the display:inline-table functionality here?

Comment: With cursor:pointer; the mouse effect is visible, but when you move your mouse from the first heading to the next from up to down, you will see that the gap between the two is not getting the mouse effect. So this is the reason why display:inline-table; comes to make it fully clickable. You can practically see this here http://jsfiddle.net/g6J3E/1/ . To make it fully clickable is  mentioned by the OP - @QiqiAbaziz

Comment: I see.. never use that one before. Is this styling supported in older browser version?

Comment: You can see the browser support for this here. http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/display%3Ainline-table - @QiqiAbaziz

Answer (score 3):

Add `cursor: pointer` to the style rule for the `class_div` class in your CSS.

Comment: Dont you see a gap when you move your mouse from first text to the next?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change style like this -

```
<div style="cursor:pointer" ....></div>.
```

Comment: Dont you see a gap when you move your mouse from first text to the next?